# How to quickly solve the following expression

Tags: arithmetic

How do I solve the following equation: ABB (base 16) + 101 (base 16)?

I know how to do it the long way (converting the bases to base 10 and then adding them). But is there a more efficient way without converting the numbers to base 10?

Comment: Just imitate the algorithm you learned in elementary school. Add column by column and "carry" when the sum exceeds $16$. In this particular easy example there are no carries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition algorithm works in any base. What you need is just the table of elementary additions (or counting with your fingers).

\begin{array}{c|cc}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 \\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12\\
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
6 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
7 & 7 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
8 & 8 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
9 & 9 & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
A & A & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
B & B & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 1A \\
C & C & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 1A & 1B \\
D & D & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 1A & 1B & 1C \\
E & E & F & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 1A & 1B & 1C & 1D \\
F & F& 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 1A & 1B & 1C & 1D & 1E \\
\end{array}

Just remember to carry. So

\begin{array}{rrrl}
A&B&B & + \\
1&0&1 & = \\
\hline
B&B&C
\end{array}

More complicated:

\begin{array}{rrrl}
\scriptstyle1&\scriptstyle1& \\
A&B&B & + \\
2&C&E & = \\
\hline
D&8&9
\end{array}
where the small ones mean “carry”.

You can note that the sum of two digits plus the possible carry cannot exceed $1F$.

The second sum in base 7:
\begin{array}{rrrrl}
  &   &   & \scriptstyle1 &   \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & + \\
  & 2 & 0 & 4 & 4 & = \\
\hline
1 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 0
\end{array}